# Expanding up or down

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

This is a jQuery function that controls a `<div>` to expand up or expand down. I am trying to simplify and optimize these lines of codes.

**Scenerio**

By default, it does not have any classes in `<div class="title-wrapper">`.

When I clicked on `<div class="title-wrapper">`, it adds `.expand-up` into this `<div>` if there `.expand-up` class. When I clicked on `<div class="title-wrapper">` it should remove `.expand-up` from `<div>` and only remove if there is `.expand-down`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.title-wrapper').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active').delay('1500').promise().done(function() {
      var filterSearch = $(this).children('.title-wrapper');
      // Check if have expand-up classes
      if (filterSearch.hasClass('expand-up')) {
        filterSearch.removeClass('expand-up');
        filterSearch.addClass('expand-down');
      } else {
        // Remove expand down if the class is existed
        if (filterSearch.hasClass('expand-down')) {
          filterSearch.removeClass('expand-down');
        }
        filterSearch.addClass('expand-up');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
}
.filter-search {
  background-color: #a78464;
}
.filter-search .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10em;
  transition: height linear 1s;
}
.filter-search .wrapper .title-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
.filter-search .wrapper .title-wrapper h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.filter-search .wrapper .title-wrapper span {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.filter-search .wrapper.active {
  height: 15em;
  transition: height linear 1s;
}
.filter-search .expand-up {
  -webkit-animation: moveUp ease-in 1;
  animation: moveUp ease-in 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}
.filter-search .expand-down,
.filter-search .expand-up {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
}
.filter-search .expand-down {
  -webkit-animation: moveDown ease-out 1;
  animation: moveDown ease-out 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: -1em;
  }
  ;
}
@keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: -1em;
  }
  ;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    margin-top: -1em;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  ;
}
@keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    margin-top: -1em;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  ;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Coding Start Here -->
<section id="filter-search" class="filter-search">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
    <div class="title-wrapper">
      <h2>Filter Search</h2>
      <span>Click to expand</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be at least as reliable to test whether the parent element `hasClass('active')`, as that class will be toggled synchronously in response to a click.

You can also benefit, syntactically, from chaining `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` (or reducing to add/remove a single class).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.title-wrapper').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $filterSearch = $(this),
   $wrapper = $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  $wrapper.stop().delay(1500).promise().done(function() {
   if ($wrapper.hasClass('active')) {
    $filterSearch.removeClass('expand-down').addClass('expand-up');
   } else {
    $filterSearch.removeClass('expand-up').addClass('expand-down');
   }
  });
 }).addClass('expand-down');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
}
.filter-search {
  background-color: #a78464;
}
.filter-search .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10em;
  transition: height linear 1s;
}
.filter-search .wrapper .title-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
.filter-search .wrapper .title-wrapper h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.filter-search .wrapper .title-wrapper span {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.filter-search .wrapper.active {
  height: 15em;
  transition: height linear 1s;
}
.filter-search .expand-up {
  -webkit-animation: moveUp ease-in 1;
  animation: moveUp ease-in 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}
.filter-search .expand-down,
.filter-search .expand-up {
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
}
.filter-search .expand-down {
  -webkit-animation: moveDown ease-out 1;
  animation: moveDown ease-out 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: .5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: -1em;
  }
  ;
}
@keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: -1em;
  }
  ;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    margin-top: -1em;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  ;
}
@keyframes moveDown {
  0% {
    margin-top: -1em;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  ;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Coding Start Here -->
<section id="filter-search" class="filter-search">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
    <div class="title-wrapper">
      <h2>Filter Search</h2>
      <span>Click to expand</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Notes:

- By testing the synchronously toggled element, you will find this solution not to get confused by rapid multiple clicks.
- `.stop()` prevents the accumulation of delay.
- The title-wrapper div needs to be initialised with `expand-down`, otherwise there's a strange glitch after first click.

Answer (score 1):

As there is only two states, up and down, we can leave out .expand-up and let it be the default state. I refactored the css and js code to just add and remove the expand-down class, for the .css file,

```
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
}
.filter-search {
    background-color: #a78464;
}
.filter-search .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 10em;
    transition: height linear 1s;
}
.filter-search .wrapper .title-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
}
.filter-search .wrapper .title-wrapper.expand-down {
    -webkit-animation: moveDown ease-out 1;
    animation: moveDown ease-out 1;
}
.filter-search .wrapper .title-wrapper h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.filter-search .wrapper .title-wrapper span {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.filter-search .wrapper.active {
    height: 15em;
    transition: height linear 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveUp {
    0% {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    to {
        margin-top: -1em;
    }
}
@keyframes moveUp {
    0% {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    to {
        margin-top: -1em;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveDown {
    0% {
        margin-top: -1em;
    }
    to {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes moveDown {
    0% {
        margin-top: -1em;
    }
    to {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

and for the .js file I changed `click()` to `on()`, in case the element will be added dynamically, `click()` would not work. Also assigning variable filterSearch earlier in the function, there should be no need to find the children with each click,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#filter-search').on('click', '.title-wrapper', function() {
        var filterSearch = $(this);

        filterSearch.parent().toggleClass('active').delay('1500').promise().done(function() {
            if (filterSearch.hasClass('expand-down')) {
                filterSearch.removeClass('expand-down');
            } else {
                filterSearch.addClass('expand-down');
            }
        });
    });
});
```